# Reading SQL file using injection and utility reader

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I've come up with a way to externalize and read in my .sql files instead of having them in-code as strings.  Note that I'm keeping the .sql file in the same package as the DAO (NOT separated into a separate resources folder).

I'm curious what others think about this methodology.

The `sqlStatement` is inject on class load (which because this is managed by Spring, on application start).  It will call the static method `SqlReader.getStatement()`, passing in the file name.

**Data Access**

```
@Repository
public class TestDAO {

    @Value("#{sqlReader.getStatement('com/mycompany/selectStatement.sql')}")
    private String selectStatement;
```

**The SqlReader is a Utility class located in another package.**

```
public class SqlReader {

    public static String getStatement(final String file) {

        try {
            return FileUtils.readFileToString(new ClassPathResource(file).getFile(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Logger.error("IOException reading file [" + file + "].", exception);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error reading for file [" + file + "]", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated:** updated the error handling. also, made SqlReader a Spring component, which cleans up the @Value expression by removing the necessity to lookup the SqlReader by type (Spring can find it by it's bean name now).

Answer (score 2):

The idea to extract SQL queries from the code into in a separate resource is good in general. Its main advantage is that when there is a non-substantial change at the database side, it might be enough to change the resource file, without recompiling the code.

However, it slightly reduces the readability: the query is in a separate file, you do not have it immediately visible near the instructions that process the `ResultSet`. That can become confusing if the query is passed to a `PreparedStatement` with a number of parameters, but everything finally depends on each case. This discussion can easily end up with arguing whether inline SQL is better than using an ORM :)

For the solution that you submitted, I can observe the following:

- each `*.sql` file can contain only one query. If there are a lot of queries used by objects within a package, this can easily pollute the folder and you'll need to be careful when choosing a naming convention for the files, otherwise one will be easily lost among them. `selectStatement.sql` is just an example and real resources should have names like `selectBookByAuthor.sql` etc.
- a single string with plain and directly usable SQL is replaced with two values which are not obvious to change and maintain if necessary: the class name (`com.mycompany.SqlReader`) and the file name (`com/mycompany/selectStatement.sql`), because both are packed in the same string expression. Would you rely on your IDE or make all changes manually for each occurrence when these two values are changing?
- the `UnsupportedOperationException` is not the best choice for this case. Logically, the operation *is* supported, but something gone wrong here and the expected predefined statement could not be read. The application is thus in an invalid state: the .sql was not included in the build sequence or a typo in the file name... I think that `IllegalStateException` is much better here. It also should be moved inside the catch block and chained with the `IOE` (`throw new IllegalStateException(ioexception);`). You should probably consider adding to the catch block other exception types, if any, that can result from calling `FileUtils.readFileToString`.

#### Another Approach

I can suggest another approach that has more or less the same result of externalizing SQL queries, but can be achieved without the dedicated `SqlReader` class, only by using the features of Spring.

The fields representing SQL queries can be initialized from property file sources:

```
@Value("${sql.select.products}")
private String selectProductsQuery;
```

The properties file must contain the key `sql.select.products`.

The annotation `@PropertySource` is used to point to the properties file to look in:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/queries.properties")
public class TestDAO { ... }
```

In `queries.properties` you just specify the queries to use:

```
sql.select.products=SELECT p.id, p.name ... FROM product p...
```

The advantages:

- it's all managed by Spring, once the configuration is set up properly.
- You have all the queries in the same file.

Comment: it was my intention to make each .sql file it's own statement -kind of goings with the pattern of making each DAO method just one database call as well (combining multiple methods/calls in a Transaction).  And I put them specifically in the same package as the rest of the logic that would call it.

Comment: I totally agree with you -the two strings used for injection can get long and potential breaking point if things change.  I'd really like to pursue the potential of a separate annotation/aspect that would inject statement without having to specify the SqlReader.getStatement() (hide the call in the aspect itself).

Comment: You're absolutely right, UnsupportedOperationException is not really appropriate.  Nor is swallowing the IOException -I'll definitely have to rework that.